# SQL Returning duplicate column values

Tags: sql, select, duplicates

What I want to do: Show only unique course IDs where each course ID shows 1 student with their project name and their most up to date project log.

Example:

```
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
| CourseID | StudentName | ProjectName     | LatestLog        |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
| 1        | Bob         | Bob's Project   | 01/09/2017 09:15 |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
| 2        | Tim         | Tim's Project   | 02/10/2017 13:00 |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
| 3        | Billy       | Billy's Project | 02/12/2017 12:45 |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

These are my database table relationships:

- A course has many students. (1 to many)
- A student has 1 student project. (1 to 1)
- A student project has many project logs. (1 to many)

For each course, I want to find the most recently submitted project log using MAX on the LogDate (DATETIME value) and the student and project name relating to that log. (**EDIT:** NOT every student belonging to the course, just the student name and project name who submitted the next project log for review, i.e. the log with the newest date possibly using the MAX function)

The problem with this SQL query is that it returns many duplicate Course IDs and every student and project name for each log is being returned.

I hope I have described the problem clearly. How can I fix this? Thank you!

```
SELECT Course.ID, -- INT
       Student.Name, -- VARCHAR(50)
       StudentProjects.Name, -- VARCHAR(50)
       MAX(ProjectLogs.LogDate) AS LogDate -- DATETIME

FROM ProjectLogs INNER JOIN
     Student ON Student.ID = ProjectLogs.StudentID INNER JOIN
     StudentProjects ON StudentProjects.ID = Student.ProjectID INNER JOIN
     Course ON Course.ID = Student.CourseID

GROUP BY Course.ID, Student.Name, StudentProjects.Name
```

Comment: Can you provide your table structures and some sample data? It looks like all your tables have an `ID` column, but according to your query, it's just the student's ID. Also, can a student be in multiple courses, and if so, can they have different studentprojects for each course, and if so, how is your `Courses` table related to the `StudentProjects` table?

Comment: @digital.aaron the ID's are all primary keys. And no the student cannot be in multiple courses, good question. I can't provide any sample data because I named the tables with different names but the logic is identical as it's company data, sorry. The courses table is indirectly related to StudentProjects because the Students table works as a bridging table because it has both foreign keys pointing to the Courses and StudentProject primary keys.

Comment: I had to rename the IDs joining the tables together. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
select Id as course_id,
       student_name,
       student_name,
       project_name,
       LogDate
 from (
SELECT Course.ID, -- INT
       Student.Name student_name, -- VARCHAR(50)
       StudentProjects.Name project_name, -- VARCHAR(50)
       ProjectLogs.LogDate,
       row_number()over(partition by Course.ID order by ProjectLogs.LogDate desc) rn      -- DATETIME
FROM ProjectLogs INNER JOIN
     Student ON Student.ID = ProjectLogs.ID INNER JOIN
     StudentProjects ON StudentProjects.ID = Student.ID INNER JOIN
     Course ON Course.ID = Student.ID
) q
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: I'm receiving an error message:

Column 'Course.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I added `GROUP BY Course.ID, Student.Name, StudentProjects.Name, ProjectLogs.LogDate` and now it works!

Comment: Yes, missed it. There is no need for a MAX aggregation for LogDate column. So you also don't need GROUP BY clause. I edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to get the max LogDate for each student, and then join that to a simplified version of your query, like this:

```
;WITH MaxLogDate AS
(
    SELECT StudentID
        ,LogDate = MAX(LogDate) 
    FROM ProjectLogs
    GROUP BY StudentID
)
SELECT c.ID
    ,s.Name
    ,sp.Name
    ,m.LogDate
FROM Courses c
INNER JOIN Student s ON s.ID = c.StudentID
INNER JOIN StudentProjects sp ON sp.StudentID = s.ID
INNER JOIN MaxLogDate m ON m.StudentID = s.ID
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it duplicates the course ID column. I would like to show unique course IDs where the other 3 columns represent the latest submitted project log (so people can review it). I don't want to see every student, just the student (and their project and log date) who is next to be reviewed